# 403 Forbidden for web root on Apache on Mac OS X v10.7, but can access user directories

Tags: osx-lion, apache-http-server

When I access http://localhost/ I get 403 Forbidden, but if I access http://localhost/~username it serves up pages. Things I've tried:

- Checking error logs
- Swapping out with original httpd conf files
- Changing DocumentRoot to my user directory (after all that should work if I can access `~username`)

I've seen 30 plus Q&A sites that all point to people having trouble with user directories being forbidden. I have the opposite problem, and so I'm tearing my hair out here.

Answer (score 3):

I actually ran into this same problem (at least the same symptoms) just today. In my case, I looked at `/var/log/apache2/error_log` and saw a bunch of errors like this:

```
[Mon Mar 19 15:30:30 2012] [error] [client ::1] Directory index forbidden by Options directive: /var/empty/
```

Then I looked in `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` and saw these two lines…

```
<IfDefine MACOSXSERVER>
DocumentRoot /var/empty
```

…and then later, these lines…

```
<IfDefine !MACOSXSERVER>
<IfDefine WEBSHARING_ON>
# Some comments were here
DocumentRoot "/Library/WebServer/Documents"
```

…so I figured that somehow `MACOSXSERVER` was getting defined, when it shouldn't be, since this machine is *not* a server machine. Then I remembered that I needed to install the Lion Server Admin tools on this machine, and the way Apple's documentation told me to do that was to install the Lion Server package from the Mac App Store on my admin machine, even though this wasn't intended to be a server machine. So maybe that actually/accidentally transmogrified my admin machine into a Mac OS X Server machine. To double-check, I ran:

```
$ sw_vers
ProductName:    Mac OS X Server
ProductVersion: 10.7.3
BuildVersion:   11D50
```

Sure enough, my machine was now reporting itself as Mac OS X Server, even though all I had wanted to do was put the Server Admin Tools on this machine.

Back to the Apache problem, I eventually found `/etc/apache2/ReadMe.txt`, which explained about those Mac OS X-specific Apache defines (be sure to read it yourself for more good info!), and then it said this:

> Those IfDefine settings – MACOSXSERVER, WEBSHARING_ON, WEBSERVICE_ON – are set or not set by Apache's launchd plist, which is present in
>   /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist.

So in my case, I chose to fix it by editing in that `launchd` `plist` for Apache to not defined `MACOSXSERVER`, since I don't really consider my machine a server, and I want to control this stuff from the Web Sharing checkbox in the Sharing panel of System Preferences, not from Server.app.

So, I edited this file:

```
/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist
```

To remove or comment out these lines, in the `ProgramArguments` array:

```
<string>-D</string>
<string>MACOSXSERVER</string>
```

I chose to comment them out by putting SGML comment start/end markers before and after them like this:

```
<!--
<string>-D</string>
<string>MACOSXSERVER</string>
-->
```

After saving my changes to that `plist` file, I restarted Apache gracefully:

```
sudo apachectl graceful
```

…and it was all better!

I may have had to reload the page in my browser a time or two if my browser had cached a "403 Forbidden" result for the page I was trying to get to.

Even if this isn't the exact same root cause of your problem, I hope my saga helps you figure out your situation.

Comment: Something to note about Lion Server is that if the Web service in Server.app is started while Web Sharing is enabled, the Web service will have a DOCUMENT_ROOT of /var/empty. You need to first disable System Preferences > Sharing > Web Sharing before starting the Web service to prevent this.